# Problem with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am dynamically creating HTML items using jQuery. Though items are dynamically created but their attributes are note. I mean if I assign `class` and `id` in the `$()` call, the elements are created without those attributes. Even my browser is showing null attributes. Problem is recognized when I tried to populate drop down according to first drop down selection.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= prescriptionnum; ++i) {
    $("<select/>", {
        class: 'selectdoctor',
        name: 'selectdoctor' + i,
        id: 'selectdoctor' + i
    }).appendTo("#prescriptiondiv").after("<br/>");

    $("<input/>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "textinput",
        name: "textinput" + i,
        id: "textinput" + i
    }).appendTo("#prescriptiondiv").after("<br/><input type='file' id='imageinput'"+ i +" class='imageinput' /><br/><br/>");
}
```

If same drop-down is created with `class selectdoctor` using HTML its working and the browser also show attributes but not for the ones that jQuery creates.

Comment: Probably because self-terminated select tags are invalid.

Comment: @Tieson: jQuery should treat `<select/>` the same as `<select>`.

Comment: You might want to use jquery tmpl for such problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `<select>`s seem to be coming out fine but you have a quoting problem with your `<input type="file">` elements, you should be using this:

```
"<br/><input type='file' id='imageinput" + i + "' class='imageinput' /><br/><br/>"
```

instead of this:

```
"<br/><input type='file' id='imageinput'"+ i +" class='imageinput' /><br/><br/>"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nUmNe/1/

As far as not getting any attributes goes, I would guess that you're using an older version of jQuery, something older than 1.4 most like. Consider this version of the fiddle that uses jQuery 1.3.2:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JbEMW/

That seems to be matching exactly what you're seeing. Also, from the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> jQuery( html, props )          **version added: 1.4**
>   **html** A string defining a single, standalone, HTML element (e.g.  or ).
>   **props** An map of attributes, events, and methods to call on the newly-created element.

So the format of the `$()` call that you're using wasn't added until version 1.4.

Comment: Yaa got the point....  Let me know reason Y I can't create input type as file using same approach. Thought its working in jsfiddle but showing as text in my browser. I had this my previous question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385733/jquery-filefield-showing-as-text-field-on-browser

Comment: In this I have to create fields using html or after. Fields created using jquery are showing null values. Its working in jsfiddle but not in browser.

Comment: @Rahul: Are you having trouble with all the form elements or just the `<input type="file">` ones?

Comment: I have same trouble with all elements as this method don't show attributes in form. I don't know how its working in jsfiddle and showing attributes their. Regarding input type file I can't create field using this method. I have put link for that doubt.

Comment: @Rahul: I don't know what you're doing different than the jsfiddle I'm as lost as you are.

Comment: Nothing I have just copy pasted same code which was working in JSfiddle. Though fields are creating dynamically but with the null attributes. My browser show field as `<select></select>`

Comment: @Rahul: I think I figured it out, please see my update. You're using jQuery 1.3, right?

Comment: I still have same issue with code, I am trying on jquery version 1.6.3

Comment: @Rahul: Sorry, I'm out of ideas and it is late here. You need to find a way to reproduce your problem in an isolated place.